using Task Spooler with python flags
I am using task Spooler and have flags in the command line to be able to add inputs through it. Is there a way to make spooler ignore this since currently I am getting an issue that it is an unknown option for spooler.
Ex:
ts python -m upload_file -f file_to_upload.txt
The -f is giving the error that it is an unkown option, but I am using it to let python know which file I am uploading
